# Disable the Chrome autofill for the Table search

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-datatables

I am using the [angular-datatables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-datatables) where chrome auto fill the table search with the email-id.

I tried to override the search with the empty string but still chrome autofill the email-id

```
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};

  this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 10,
  "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"lip><"clear">',
  responsive: true,
  search :{
    search : " "
    }

};
```

so here **search : "anything"** it searchs for anything in the table, i tried null option empty string chrome auto fills with email id.

how can force chrome not to fill email in the search input.

Comment: Start by not wrapping the table inside a form ...

Comment: how to do that @davidkonrad

Comment: I guess you have the entire table inside `<form></form>` ...? Chrome should not autopopulate an input without the form tag.

Comment: that is just a normal table when the component loads table with options loads from the type script check this link [Angular-datables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/zero-config) @davidkornad

Answer (score 1):

I look in the Github repository to see how the hell it works.

I found a dependency on the jquery library in this documentation:

http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started

**npm install datatables.net --save**

Later i searched inside of the jquery library for the input field.

/node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js

in the **line 4182** i just added a property **autocomplete="off"**

```
var input = '<input type="search" autocomplete="off" class="'+classes.sFilterInput+'"/>';
```

Yep, it is a bit tricky, if it works let me know to make an pull request in the datatables github repository.

> Update

Chrome intentionaly ignores **autocomplete="off"** and **autocomplete="false"** so use **autocomplete="new-search"**

I do not add the same tag in jquery.dataTables.min.js, and it is certain that the compiler is using the .min.js file

Find the next expresion inside of

*/node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js*

```
'<input type="search" class="'+b.sFilterInput+'"/>'
```

And replace for:

```
'<input type="search" autocomplete="new-search" class="'+b.sFilterInput+'"/>'
```

Comment: i tried this one still it is not working chrome still autofill search bar with the email-id @blackMagician

Comment: If you overwrite the input you should also add a random id attribute. Chrome uses the id of an input to find autofill recommendations.

Comment: In chrome to use autocomplete=off you have to add the input into a form

Comment: Even tried with the updated code its not working @blackMagician

Answer (score 0):

if its acceptable for you here is a custom search for tables what im using:

html:

```
<form  [formGroup]="searchTableForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="tableSearchBox">
      <input class="tableSearch" required formControlName="search">
      </div>
</form>
```

.ts:

```
onSubmit(){
   this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api)=>{
     dtInstance.search(this.searchTableForm.value.search).draw()
   })
}
```

im running it every time when the forms value changes

Comment: as the angular-datatables is giving the search option i want to disable auto fill ,I dont want to create a new function just to search and again render into the table. @GaryB

Comment: okay then there is a SO post https://stackoverflow.com/a/30976223/9945674